# Почему неправильно считается покрытие в коде с абстрактным классом / методом

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, code-coverage

Вот так выглядит код, который я хочу протестировать:

```
class AbstractWrapper(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def func(self) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError  # *


class Wrapper(AbstractWrapper):
    def func(self) -> None:
        print(1)  # *
```

Я написал pytest тесты и запустил команду `pytest --cov --cov-report=html`. Но почему-то в отчете покзаывает, что строки со `*` не покрыты тестами. Но тесты работают корректно и проверяют код (с неправильными входными данными тесты не проходят, с правильными - проходят).

Как это можно исправить, может я не ту команду использую?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прежде всего, вы звездочкой отметили, что `print(1)` у вас показывает не покрытым, но у меня такая проблема не воспроизводится. Этот `print` фактически в процессе выполнения теста выполняется, и в покрытии он учитывается.

Далее, по поводу абстрактного метода. Если вы тестируете только `Wrapper`, то исходный не переопределенный метод останется не покрытым, т.к. фактически исходный метод не вызывается:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class AbstractWrapper(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def func(self) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError


class Wrapper(AbstractWrapper):
    def func(self) -> None:
        print(1)  # *


def test_wrapper(capsys):
    wrapper = Wrapper()
    wrapper.func()
    captured = capsys.readouterr()
    assert captured.out == "1\n"
```

В данном случае все пишу в одном файле `test.py`, тесты запускаю командой

```
pytest test.py --cov --cov-report=html
```

Покрытие:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно или сделать метод не абстрактным, чтобы можно было отнаследоваться и вызвать исходный вариант метода (проверить, что он действительно кидает `NotImplementedError`):

```
from abc import ABC
import pytest


class AbstractWrapper(ABC):
    def func(self) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError


...


def test_abstract_wrapper():
    class Test(AbstractWrapper):
        pass

    wrapper = Test()
    with pytest.raises(NotImplementedError):
        wrapper.func()
```

Покрытие:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Либо добавляете комментарий `# pragma: no cover` абстрактному методу, тогда покрытие по нему не будет учитываться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также можно добавить декоратор абстрактного метода в `exclude_also` в конфиге `.coveragerc` (конфиг нужно положить в папку, откуда вызываете pytest) - это наиболее удобный вариант, на мой взгляд:

```
[report]
exclude_also =
    @(abc\.)?abstractmethod
```

Полный пример из документации модуля `coverage.py` ([Excluding code from coverage.py / Advanced exclusion](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/excluding.html#advanced-exclusion)):

```
[report]
exclude_also =
    def __repr__
    if self.debug:
    if settings.DEBUG
    raise AssertionError
    raise NotImplementedError
    if 0:
    if __name__ == .__main__.:
    if TYPE_CHECKING:
    class .*\bProtocol\):
    @(abc\.)?abstractmethod
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]